# How to manage files between Main Domain to Sub domain in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an e-commerece website with an admin panel. I used a separate sub-domain for the admin panel. But I don't understand how to access product image file from sub domain to main website in ASP.NET MVC.

When I upload a product image in the sub domain, it should be accessible in both domains.